# You may specify either a ''value'' attribute or a body for the column component, but not both in Wrapper Class

Tags: visualforce, wrapper-class

I have a requirement like Display Account and its related contacts in proper tabular format by using Wrapper Class.
but i am getting this error.
You may specify either a ''value'' attribute or a body for the column component, but not both

vf code

```
apex:page controller="WrapperAccountCtrl" sidebar="false">

      apex:form >

         apex:pageBlock >
             apex:pageBlockTable value="{!conlist}" var="c">    
                 apex:column value="{!c.Account.Name}">
                 apex:column value="{!c.Name}"/>
                 /apex:column>
             /apex:pageBlockTable>
         /apex:pageBlock>
     /apex:form> 
/apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class WrapperAccountCtrl {

    public List<Account> acclist{get;set;}
    public List<Contact> conlist{get;set;} 
    public List<MyWrapper> wap{get;set;}

    public WrapperAccountCtrl() 
    {
        acclist=[Select id,name from Account];

        conlist=[Select id,name,AccountID,Account.Name from contact where AccountID IN:acclist];

        system.debug('Size----'+conlist.size());

         wap=new List<MyWrapper>();

         for(integer i=0;i<acclist.size();i++)
         {
             wap.add(new MyWrapper(conlist,acclist[i]));

         }

    }



    public class MyWrapper
    {

        public Account accn{get;set;}

        public List<Contact>conrec{get;set;}

        public MyWrapper(List<Contact> con,Account acc)
        {
            accn=acc;
            conrec=con;    

        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first column definition:

```
<apex:column value="{!c.Account.Name}">
```

is missing the slash that makes it a self closing tag:

```
<apex:column value="{!c.Account.Name}"/>
```

and so the Visualforce compiler thinks the next `apex:column` is the body of the first.

Instead you need:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!conlist}" var="c">
    <apex:column value="{!c.Account.Name}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!c.Name}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```